# Lookahead not working in a "not followed by" regex

Tags: regex

In this example:

```
jump (foo) (db);
jump (foo);
call(bar)(db);
```

I should match only the second line which contains a `jump|call|rts|rti` but not followed with `(db)`.

```
/
(?:jump|call|rts|rti)\s*
\(\w+\)\s*
(?!\(db\)) # Not followed with (db)
/xi
```

https://regex101.com/r/fS2gA0/1

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the regex engine matches the last whitespaces with `\s*` the lookahead is tested and fails (because of the presence of `(db)`).

So what happens after?
The regex engine backtracks (it tries to find an other way to make succeed the pattern). It gives back the last whitespace and now the new position isn't followed by `(db)` but by the space (and the lookahead succeeds).

The way to prevent this behaviour is to use possessive quantifiers that forces the regex engine to not backtrack: so `\s*+`

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/hL2fX6/1)

You can clearly see the behaviour with the regex101 debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Your online regex tester shows that it matches `jump (foo)`, not `jump (foo)` . `jump (foo)` is not followed by `(db)`. It is followed by  `(db)`, but your regex does not have a problem with that. Yes, you have `\s*` in your regex, but that still allows for a match that does not include the spaces.

To fix the problem, you can move (or copy) the `\s*` into your negative lookahead.

Answer (score 1):

Add semicolon at the end, here a perl script that does the job:

```
my $re = qr~
(?:jump|call|rts|rti)\s*
\(\w+\)\s*
(?!\(db\)) # Not followed with (db)
;  # <-- here
~xi;

while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    say /$re/ ? "OK: $_" : "KO: $_";
}

__DATA__
jump (foo) (db);
jump (foo);
call(bar)(db);
```

**Output:**

```
KO: jump (foo) (db);
OK: jump (foo);
KO: call(bar)(db);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\(\w+\)\s*
```

can be changed to:

```
\(\w+\)\s
```

otherwise, lookahead passes because of the space being in the lookahead.